# How can I find an adult-sized passenger trailer?

Tags: trailer

Are bicyle passenger trailers limited to child sizes? I have looked for larger sizes but most stores only offer trailers sized for children. It would be an inline trailer sized for a small to medium size female, 160 pounds (72kg) or less.

Comment: Would it also fit small males, 160 pounds and under?

Comment: How about a pedicab?

Comment: Who is the trailer for?  Also, would a tandem (a bicycle built for two) work?

Answer (score 5):

Equinox makes a larger version of a child carrier for passengers up to 200 lbs.  See: http://www.equinoxtrailers.com/store/item/19

Answer (score 2):

Wike trailers makes a Special Needs trailer:
http://www.wicycle.com/special_needs_extra_large_bicycle_trailer.php

Answer (score 0):

Pashley used to do something a bit like this that I thought went to adult sizes:
http://www.cyclesense.co.uk/m17b0s435p7209/MISSION-Piggy-back-Mk11-special-needs-24-inch-wheel-2012 (And that might be big enough for you.)

Looking at http://www.castlecaremobility.com/pashleyaccessories2.htm maybe the Pashley was only child size anyway.

I've never seen a large equivalent of the sort of trailers that small children just sit in though.

If by "inline", you mean a single wheel trailer like the Bob Yak, I've never seen a passenger version of them, only two-wheeled.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen a commercial trailer that allows for passive adult passengers. There are the [Caboose Trailer Bike](http://www.caboosetrailerbike.com/) and home made [Recumbent Bike Trailer](http://www.ihpva.org/projects/tstrike/rectrailer.htm) as alternatives.  Also, [Xtracycle](http://www.xtracycle.com/) supports passengers up to 200 pounds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I've seen photos of one of the heavy-duty eurobikes with a heavy trailer attached.  Don't know any brands, though, or where you'd get one.

Answer (score 0):

Blue Sky Cycle Carts makes one - we have had it for more than 10 years!