# Are there adult bicycle passenger trailers for adults in Australia?

Tags: trailer

I understand that there are kids bicycle trailers, but are there adult bicycle trailers? Specifically selling in Australia?

Comment: Try checking the answers in this similar question. http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/12884/bicycle-passenger-trailers  Most of the adult trailers are for special needs, and don't sell in high valume, so they get quite expensive.  Shipping costs to Australia probably wouldn't change the price by a large amount (compared to the price of the trailer) and most are small businesses who would probably work with you to get the product shipped to you.

Comment: You might consider either modifying a cargo trailer (if you can find one) or, say, finding a used racing wheelchair and adding a yoke to it to attach to the bike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are recumbent trikes available here in Australia which link together so that one tows the other - if the back person chooses not to pedal then it would effectively be a trailer, with the rear person just sitting like in chair.   These would be much lower and more stable than having a scaled-up kiddie trailer or wheelchair.

For slow speeds and a smallish adult have a look at a 'bakfiets' style cargo bikes, there are Australian brands.

A longtail cargo bike might be an option too, if the passenger is able to sit up on one. (I use one of these for larger kids)

Here are some of the specific brands and shops in Australia:
Linking recumbent trikes: 
Hase Kettweisel

Bakfiets style:
Kangaroo Bike (May or may not be that brand specifically ... I have seen this style bike ridden in Australia with a kangaroo logo on the side)

Longtail cargo bikes:
Kona Ute
Yuba Mundo
Surly Big Dummy
Xtracycle conversion kits

Recumbent shops:
Flying Furniture (Canberra dealer for recumbents and other interesting machines for cargo and multiple people)
Trisled (Manufacturer in Melbourne, might be worth asking them about something custom built...)

Comment: Also Greenspeed in Melbourne who manufacture a delta trike that can be linked, and have manufactured a trailer to carry an adult behind a tandem trike (the "Lamb Tandem" named for the people who commissioned it)

Answer (score 5):

In Victoria it's unlikely because until recently it was illegal for anyone over the age of *10* to ride in a bicycle trailer. And now you can tow someone **only** as long as:

- they have a medical certificate (signed by a medical practitioner)
  showing they have a disability or medical condition which makes it
  reasonable for them to ride in the trailer
- you and your passenger comply with any conditions on the certificate
- the certificate has an expiry date (if the medical condition or disability is temporary)
- they carry the certificate and can show it to the police when asked.

No, really. Because for some reason a bike trailer is safe for kids, but unsafe for adults. See [Vic Roads ... bicycles](https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/safety-and-road-rules/road-rules/a-to-z-of-road-rules/bicycles) and scroll down to "Bicycle trailers".

Just more wisdom from the revheads who design our roads and rules.

Comment: Ah well, pity.... we need to be more European....

Comment: However the chances of a police officer knowing this law, and choosing to apply it, is low. Most will ignore bicycles unless instructed by their superiors, and will only try to issue a ticket if you're doing something stupid. I have ridden some very odd bicycles around Melbourne and surrounds and never had a problem (even when what I was doing was not lawful)

Comment: Good work @stib. When I found the broken link I wanted to simply add the new one. Then I found the rules had changed, but I didn't think I should substantially change your answer.